# Bulk INSERT into Azure SQL from BLOB saying file could not be opened

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to bulk_insert from BLOB container into Azure SQL.

This is my StorageAccount: SanStore
Container: SanContainer

Here is the script

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
LOCATION = 'https://sanstore.blob.core.windows.net/sancontainer'
);

BULK INSERT ado_workitem
FROM 'WorkItemsComplete_Till_august_10.csv'
WITH (  DATA_SOURCE = 'SanStore',
        FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
        ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
        FIRSTROW=2,
        BATCHSIZE=10000);
```

The file is already in blob container which is I verified. But when executing the command it triggers

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Cannot bulk load because the file "WorkItemsComplete_Till_august_10.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 161(The specified path is invalid.).
```

Please note I am trying this script from my local management studio, logging into the SQL server using Identity authentication.

I missed another point. The file size is ~300MB. Does that makes any issues. I have heard people play with bulk insert using 1 GB files

Comment: Should the `create external data source` command include a `credential` parameter? [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql#g-create-an-external-data-source-for-bulk-operations-retrieving-data-from-azure-storage)

Comment: I believe only SAS tokens are supported for credentials. Considering access keys usage is blocked in your organization, can you try by creating a [`user delegation SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using SAS key to access storage. Azure AD identities and managed identities are  [currently not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/doc-changes-updates-release-notes?tabs=single-database#bulk-insert-and-backuprestore-statements-cannot-use-managed-identity-to-access-azure-storage).

Also make sure that blob storage you are reading data from has is Public. Private IPs for blob storage and service endpoints are currently not supported.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since I can see in error that `file cannot be opened` and the `specified path is invalid.`

try copy below just in case to rule out syntax issue:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
LOCATION = 'https://sanstore.blob.core.windows.net/sancontainer/folder'
);

BULK INSERT ado_workitem
FROM 'WorkItemsComplete_Till_august_10.csv'
WITH (  DATA_SOURCE = 'SanStore',
        FIELDTERMINATOR=",",
        ROWTERMINATOR="\n",
        FIRSTROW=2,
        BATCHSIZE=10000);
```

Further you can refer:  [Troubleshooting BULK INSERT and OPENROWSET issues on Azure SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/troubleshooting-bulk-insert-and-openrowset-issues-on-azure-sql/ba-p/664734)

Comment: Unfortuantely SAS key disabled in our environment due to security constraints. Only Azure AD Auth enabled

Comment: Unfortunately, as per [Known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/doc-changes-updates-release-notes?tabs=single-database#known-issues) you can only use SAS Key. As a user delegation SAS applies to Blob storage only, you can try convincing them to consider type  [User delegation SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#user-delegation-sas). Which is secured with (Azure AD) credentials and also by the permissions specified for the SAS.